# Next.js : serve different page for same url for different domains

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, next.js14

I have single Next.js application in which i have to maintain the different pages for same url, but there are some common pages which can be access by both domains.

E.g. I have a domain like **abc.com** and **xyz.com**,
When **abc.com/home** is called i want to serve a **home** page for website **abc** and same for **xyz.com/home** it should open **home** page for website **xyz**

but there is a common page for both like **contact**, so for both **abc.com/contact** and **xyz.com/contact** should open the same page, just a layout for that page will be different

I have tried this with **server.ts**

```
const { createServer } = require('http')
const { parse } = require('url')
const next = require('next')
 
const dev = process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
const hostname = 'localhost'
const port = 3000
// when using middleware `hostname` and `port` must be provided below
const app = next({ dev, hostname, port })
const handle = app.getRequestHandler()
 
app.prepare().then(() => {
  createServer(async (req, res) => {
    try {
      // Be sure to pass `true` as the second argument to `url.parse`.
      // This tells it to parse the query portion of the URL.
      const host = req.headers.host;

       if (host === 'abc.com') {
         await app.render(req, res, '/abc', req.query)
       } else if (host === 'xyz.com') {
         await app.render(req, res, '/xyz',req.query)
       } else {
        await handle(req, res)
       }
    } catch (err) {
      console.error('Error occurred handling', req.url, err)
      res.statusCode = 500
      res.end('internal server error')
    }
  })
    .once('error', (err) => {
      console.error(err)
      process.exit(1)
    })
    .listen(port, () => {
      console.log(`> Ready on http://${hostname}:${port}`)
    })
})
```

and my file structure is like

```
my-project
  --src
    --app
      --page.tsx
      --layout.tsx
      --abc
        --layout.tsx
        --home
          --page.tsx
      --xyz
        --layout.tsx
        --home
          --page.tsx
      --contact (in this layout should be used from abc or xyz as per domain)
        page.tsx
  -- other nextjs folders
```

but in this i cannot access the **contact** page both the domain

What should i do to achieve this in nextjs?